# Xamarin Forms - Library not found for -lrealm-wrapper

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried to add Realm from NuGet Packages to iOS project, but when I build, I get some errors, can someone please help me?

The image below shows the errors:

[image]

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please post the code you have written so far and have a look at this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this question,could you please share the steps of reproducing this question?